# How do I fix an invalid configuration error for a rewrite section in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

My web.config has the following `rewrite` element commented out on my machine, but when deployed to our QA server, it is not commented out. The difference between my machine and QA is that QA has an SSL certificate and my machine doesn't.

```
<system.webServer>
  <!--<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <clear/>
      <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>-->
```

When this is not commented out, I get a 500.19 error, invalid configuration? My question is, how do I get this `rewrite` to work on my machine? I guess installing a certificate is one part of the solution, but would like to know, if anything, what else I will have to do, in IIS etc. to get the project to run without this config element being commented out?

Comment: Why not add a new condition `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />` (assuming `localhost` is the hostname when you're running locally)?

Comment: @haim770 Thanks, but what exactly will that do? The `rewrite` as is, works 100% when deployed to our dev, QA, and prod environments, and I don't at all want to alter how it works on those. I would much rather my machine were configured for it to work as is.

Comment: It adds a conditions to perform the "HTTPS check & redirect" only on non-`localhost` machines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of transforming the *web.config*

[image]

Reference: [Transform web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and additional resources to get a better understanding of how to apply the transformation.

Include the `<rewrite>` element in the release config

For example

*Web.Release.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        <clear/>
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

and it will insert the `<rewrite>` element into the config file as part of the build process when the site is published (Release mode)

The default version can be used as desired on your local machine where that element is not part of the main config file since it is only needed in release builds.

*Web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- ... -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.web>

  <!-- populated as desired, excluding the <rewrite> element -->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Single configuration approach**

In this case, on your local machine, You have to install *URL rewrite module* which is **not** included in IIS by default (use web platform installer) in addition to *installing a certificate*. In this way, IIS can use the `rewrite` block inside configuration.

**Dynamic configuration based on environment**

In this case, you let compiler use the relevant configuration based on environment. As @Nkosi mentioned, there are two versions of configuration file (nested) for each environment :

- *Web.Debug.config*
- *Web.Release.config*